# Background image not displayed in Ubuntu with Gnome (Xorg)

Tags: 20.04, gnome, xorg

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome (Xorg) as desktop environment. I am facing the problem that my desktop background always remains black unless I press the "Super" key:

Without super key:

[image]

With super key:

[image]

I have tried tried solutions for older distributions (e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119497/my-ubuntu-background-is-totally-black-even-after-opening-programs-such-as-termi)), all unsuccessful. Has anyone faced the same problem before and might know a solution?

I am using:

- Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.11.0-46-generic
- GNOME Shell 3.36.9
- GTK 3.24.20
- X.Org X Server 1.20.13
- GPU: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CML GT2)

Comment: Add information on graphics card to your question: probably related with graphics drivers.

Comment: The computer is equipped with a "Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CML GT2)" GPU

Comment: Please include any relevant information in your question: use "edit". Comments only serve to improve questions and answers, and are not always read or may become hidden.